# Need to add source attribute in a google gadget?

Tags: javascript, attributes, replace

so I've been trying to make a gadget for google sites and have created two options to insert urls to a .ogg and .mp3 files. Here is my code:

```
<UserPref name="ogguri" display_name="Url to your .ogg file" datatype="string" required="true" />
<UserPref name="mp3uri" display_name="Url to your .mp3 file" datatype="string" required="true" />
<Content type="html">
<script>
   gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(doRender);

   function doRender(){
      var prefs = new gadgets.Prefs();
      var ogguri = prefs.getString('ogguri');
      var mp3uri = prefs.getString('mp3uri');  
      var ogg = document.getElementById("ogg"); 
      var mp3 = document.getElementById("mp3");
  //add proper attributes
      ogg.setAttribute("src", "ogguri"); 
      mp3.setAttribute("src", "mp3uri");
   }
</script>
```

I am having trouble as the out put of the `<audio>` elements adds the src attribute but it prints out as `src="ogguri"` or `src="mp3uri"` I am having trouble seeing where the problem is or what I should do. It seems to me that the ogguri and mp3uri are not getting defined.